# Database structure Menu Item

Tags: menus, database

I want to write the menu items into the database using a program. I also saw the structure of the database here, but I don't understand the dependency of the menu items. I also created a test menu with test points, but I can't figure it out either. Does anyone know how the structure of the menu items is?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Comment: If you interact directly with the database then lots of actions and filters will have no opportunity to run. This could cause problems. Have you considered using the REST API instead to modify/add/update nav menus? Doing it that way means you don't need to know how they're stored, and you can use standard tools and JS as long as you have authentication setup

Comment: Hey. i got view a lot of Rest API tutorial on YT. But thats not solve my Problem. Because i have a lot of Menuitem and if i use the rest api auf Wordpress/Woocommerce they arent fast enough. Example: my File with the data of the production are 37 MB large. If i want to import them, after 2 days only importing, the reached 25% only. so i must write them myself in the database and i must know, how the menu item is build because i must need to link the Productcategorys to them.

Comment: You don't have to make your requests 1 by 1 and you don't need all your plugins activated at the same time while you do it. Also that's a stupendous number of menus, what are these menus for? It sounds like you've done something manually that could be done dynamically in code. REST API requests shouldn't take very long, but if you have a very slow site that takes longer than a second to handle a HTTP request then you have a optimisation to do, even if all your menus had been imported. Can you add bg and context?